# ToPagedList is not giving values while I am trying for second page in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am using Entity Framework for fetch records in Asp.net MVC. For that I am using `PagedList` for pagination. In that while I am fetching records for page 1 then it's giving me proper records while I am trying to fetch records for second page then it's not returning records.

```
 public MW_AppointmentsWithCount CurrentAppointmentsWithLanguage(int PatientID, int languageId, int page, int pageSize)
        {
            MW_AppointmentsWithCount lstAppCount = new MW_AppointmentsWithCount();
            using (MWCoreEntity db = new MWCoreEntity())
            {
                List<MW_Appointments> result = db.MW_Appointments.Where(x => x.PatientID == PatientID && x.Status < 5).ToList();
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    item.MW_Consultants = db.MW_Consultants.Where(x => x.UserId == item.ConsultantID && x.LanguageID == languageId).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                lstAppCount.mW_Appointments = result;
                lstAppCount.totalCount = result.Count();

                PagedList<MW_Appointments> model = new PagedList<MW_Appointments>(result, page, pageSize);

                //in below line when there is page 2 then it's giving 0 values. While in model there is records as per pageSize and page.
                lstAppCount.mW_Appointments = model.ToPagedList(page, pageSize).ToList();

                return lstAppCount;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 MW_AppointmentsWithCount CurrentAppointmentsWithLanguage(int PatientID, int languageId, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        MW_AppointmentsWithCount lstAppCount = new MW_AppointmentsWithCount();
        using (MWCoreEntity db = new MWCoreEntity())
        {
            List<MW_Appointments> result = db.MW_Appointments.Where(x => x.PatientID == PatientID && x.Status < 5).ToList();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                item.MW_Consultants = db.MW_Consultants.Where(x => x.UserId == item.ConsultantID && x.LanguageID == languageId).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            lstAppCount.mW_Appointments = result;
            lstAppCount.totalCount = result.Count();

            return result.ToPagedList(page, pageSize);


        }
    }
```